# jquery validation check what submit is clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to make some validation,
check what is button user clicked.

I have button submit like this

```
<form id="form-post">
    <button type="submit" id="one"> ONE </button>
    <button type="submit" id="two"> TWO </button>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form-post').submit(function() {   
        //here for the validation
        $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: 'sta=' +GetButtonId,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.alert-warning').html(data);
            }
            return false;
        });
```

how to get button id to data: 'sta=' +GetButtonId with validation in jquery

example

```
if(button.submit.one.click) {
    var GetButtonId = "one";
} else {
    var GetButtonId = "two";
}
```

Comment: what is one and two for ? what you want to achieve exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the Ajax request on button click and to know which button is clicked you can do this -

```
$('button').click(function(e){
      $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: $("#form-post").attr('action'),
            data: 'sta=' + $(this).attr('id'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('.alert-warning').html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

Since you are not doing 'normal' form submit instead an Ajax POST,
You may want to prevent the default behavior of form submit -

```
$("#form-post").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button[type="submit"]").click(function(event) {
           //prevent default form post submission
           event.preventDefault();
           // get ID of button
              var id=$(this).attr("id");
           //then make jQuery ajax call passing id.
          $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: 'sta=' +id,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.alert-warning').html(data);
            }

         });

    });
});
```